# Autodesk GuiViewer3D initialize gives an error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Following is my code

```js
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }
```

but it still gives an error as follows

[image: error]

Please advise me where I have done wrong ?

using viewer V6

update :

```js
 var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
 viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
```

error stack

```
SettingsPanel.js:377 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tBodies' of null
    at v.l.addCheckbox (SettingsPanel.js:377)
    at v.addCheckbox (ViewerSettingsPanel.js:137)
    at v.createNavigationPanel (ViewerSettingsPanel.js:328)
    at new v (ViewerSettingsPanel.js:64)
    at D.createSettingsPanel (GuiViewer3D.js:837)
    at D.initModelTools (GuiViewer3D.js:926)
    at D.createUI (GuiViewer3D.js:369)
    at GuiViewer3D.js:291
    at GuiViewer3D.js:301
l.addCheckbox   @   SettingsPanel.js:377
v.addCheckbox   @   ViewerSettingsPanel.js:137
v.createNavigationPanel @   ViewerSettingsPanel.js:328
v   @   ViewerSettingsPanel.js:64
D.createSettingsPanel   @   GuiViewer3D.js:837
D.initModelTools    @   GuiViewer3D.js:926
D.createUI  @   GuiViewer3D.js:369
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:291
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:301
```

[new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXGI7.png)

Thank you
Cheers

Comment: The error comes from a code that's trying to initialize the viewer UI, and it indicates that a certain HTML is missing. First of all check if there is a `<div>` in your markup with the ID "forgeViewer". Second, make sure that the viewer is not initialized multiple times. From your code it looks like you are initializing the viewer in a `getForgeToken` function? Is that intentional? Perhaps sharing the entire codebase would help us debug the issue further.

Comment: hi @PetrBroz

i think the issue is what you have mentioned in the "second" point.  I'm trying to add a markup extension . I think I might have to get the existing viewer and add it .

thank you,
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 6 and older, the `GuiViewer3D` class is in a different namespace: `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D`.

Since version 7 the fully qualified name is `Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D`.

Comment: I changed the code as " viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);" 



now I get this  error 

SettingsPanel.js:377 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tBodies' of null

Comment: Not sure about that one. Any chance you could find the entire call stack where this error is thrown?